# How to handle IAM credential rotations when accessing AWS services

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam

We have an API Gateway configured to receive external calls to put objects to our S3 bucket. When trying to do it programmatically in Java we have to get the Access Key and Secret Access Key and attach it to the request to AWS.

Our service (Salesforce) that calls the API gateway resides externally to the AWS service and the Access Key and Secret Access Key of an IAM user we are using rotates monthly which means, in the worse case, we have to manually get these keys and copy them over to the specific location.

This does not seem to be an elegant solution, can anyone with experience provide better ways to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS IAM allows two Access Keys to be active simultaneously. This permits a long rotation period.

For example:

- Access Key 1 is in use and is stored in Salesforce
- At end of month:

  - A 2nd Access Key is generated
  - Both keys are valid
  - The new key is copied into Salesforce
- Wait 24 hours, then delete the previous key

This allows for a longer "transition period", without having to perform updates in both systems simultaneously.

The above AWS processes can be performed by via API calls. If the external system also permits credential updates via API, then this entire operation can be automated.

Comment: thanks it looks like there's no good way other than copy & paste the keys in each rotation.

Comment: You can perform the rotation using API calls, such as [`create_access_key()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.create_access_key). Salesforce also has API calls that you could use to update details.